# Importing CSV data into MYSQL via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am working on a website which uses data from a CRM system, this data is in CSV format but when im trying to import into MYSQL via php something is corrupting and forcing a record to split and take 2 rows.  Example of CSV field below - something in it is causing the error/split to another row in the database.  It seems to be some kind of character but ive tried to replace the culprit ones.  Any ideas would be GREATLY appreciated as I have spent ages trying to figure this out!! im using fgetcsv to import.  I can import the csv file no problem via phpmyadmin

"GREAT FIRST TIME PURCHASE TWO BED END TERRACED IN A POPULAR LOCATION.  Pleased to have available this well presented two bed end terraced situated in an ideal location for all local amenities, just a short stroll to the Stretford Arndale Centre and close proximity to the Metrolink tram station for commuting into the city centre and Media city.  The accommodation briefly comprising, lounge with staircase leading to first floor, kitchen/diner and cellar used for storage.  Whilst to the first floor there are two double bedrooms and a family bathroom.  OUTSIDE Enclosed Court yard to the rear.  Private parking space."

Comment: Do you grant us permission to remotely read your mind to find out how the code producing the incorrect results looks like?

Comment: Come of Chris - If you cannot debug it with the Code and Data in front of you **what chance do you think we have** based on what you have given us to look at!? Get a grip man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a comma in your text which is causing data to split:

"GREAT FIRST TIME PURCHASE TWO BED END TERRACED IN A POPULAR LOCATION. Pleased to have available this well presented two bed end terraced situated in an ideal location for all local **amenities, just** a short stroll to the Stretford Arndale Centre and close proximity to the Metrolink tram station for commuting into the city centre and Media city. The accommodation briefly **comprising, lounge** with staircase leading to first **floor, kitchen/diner** and cellar used for storage. Whilst to the first floor there are two double bedrooms and a family bathroom. OUTSIDE Enclosed Court yard to the rear. Private parking space."

Comment: Don't forget "comprising," and "amenities,"

Comment: Thanks @user1612272 I missed that.

Comment: If they are inside doublequotes `"` they should be safe though

Comment: Thanks guys used LOAD DATA INFILE instead which worked!

Comment: @ChristopherPeacock Its rather misleading to accept an answer that has nothing to do with your solution.

Comment: @RiggsFolly why cant be the answer considered as solution? The  solution highlighted in the answer can actually get the data inserted in the database. He used a different method to insert data thats his call.

Comment: Well for a start, removing required text from a string in order to get it loaded on a database is not a solution to anything. Thats like saying I cannot get 1,000,000 to go into a `small int` so just put `65535` in there and hope for the best

Comment: With all due respect,  I have never suggested that OP needs to remove the commas or data enclosing commas to get the data inserted. I have just highlighted the root cause of the issue are commas in between the text. He can enclose it in double quotes as per your suggestion itself to get it inserted.